# Local Backup vSphere SDK

Tags: c#, vsphere

I'm working on a desktop application that purpose is saving a backup of a Virtual Machine stored in an ESX without vCenter in local storage. I'm currently using the vSphere SDK for C# and I'm working on a WinForm. I have **a box** for selecting the machine and **a button** to make a backup of selected running Virtual Machine on my laptop. I can't find any method in the vSphere SDK to help me for backing up a running VM.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please do more description of your problem.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and i found this solution but through PowerCLI.
I made a power shell script that allowed me to export the VM as a .OVA file in a local storage. 
You cannot perform the Export command when the VM is powered ON. The only way to perform a backup of a powered on VM ,is having a licence with the vCenter.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Following up on Octopi's response, Exporting an OVA/OVF is probably the best, built-in, backup method. The vSphere Management SDK Programming Reference has a section on it that you can review to hopefully help: https://code.vmware.com/docs/6611/vmware-vsphere-web-services-sdk-programming-guide#/doc/GUID-4A7882E4-7FB2-4994-AD48-A04CF76B192B.html